# JFrame very small using null layout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Hi I am writing a simple program to display a frame.
However the frame turns out real small when I type setLayout(null);
But if i ignore this command, the button is always at the top center
Can some one point out my error?

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

class theframe {

    private static void create() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Insets insets = frame.getInsets();
        frame.setSize(500 + insets.left + insets.right, 350 + insets.top + insets.bottom);
        add(frame.getContentPane()); //my function add
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void add(Container pane) {
        pane.setLayout(null);
        Insets insets = pane.getInsets();

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 350));

        JButton b1 = new JButton("one");
        Dimension size = b1.getPreferredSize();
        b1.setBounds(25 + insets.left, 5 + insets.top, size.width, size.height);

        pane.add(p1);
        p1.add(b1);
    }

    public static void main(String Args[]) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                create();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The rule seems to be "No UI without a LayoutManager".

Comment: Try to set the size of the `JFrame` after packing it. Else `pack()` will reset your size.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't get it.
I was learning from oracle tutorial and the were using null layout
I don't know why it happens for my run

Comment: @UwePlonus
Yes that worked but the button and panel are no longer visible

Comment: Provide ASCII art of the GUI as it should appear in smallest size and (if resizable) with extra width/height.

Answer (score 5):

You're calling `pack()` method with absolute positioning (*null* layout), you should use LayoutManager instead of using setting the layout to `null`.

Just remove this line:

```
pane.setLayout(null);
```

**NOTE:** take my advice and learn yourself `LayoutManagers`, because if you refuse to learn, you'll probably go to `null` layout, yes,it is easier but highly recommended to not use it.

Some basic things you must know:

1. The default layout of `JFrame` is [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#border), which there only five locations you can put your components in as shown in the link.
2. [FlowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#flow) is the default layout manager for every JPanel. It simply lays out components in a single row, starting a new row if its container is not sufficiently wide.

After all, read more about [LayoutManagers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) before starting using swing, belive me it makes your work very easier, just try it, it's amazing.

Comment: Yes but the button is always centered at the top and I cannot set its position on the panel

Comment: @Azdad using `pane.setPreferredSize(someDimension);` will solve the problem, you don't need to use a layout manager. It is better to use it when creating GUI applications, but the null layout is not the problem here.

Comment: *"I cannot set its position on the panel"*  You **should not** be setting the position of components.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Why not?
Layout managers are a bit complex aren't they?

Comment: Yes, because by default the container of the frame adds the panel to the `CENTER`.

Comment: *"Why not?"*  For the reasons I put in a comment 7 minutes ago. *"Layout managers are a bit complex aren't they?"*  Less complex than figuring out positioning of components by yourself (for the **same** reasons).

Comment: @BackSlash: it's not about his problem, it's about changing him to not use `null` layout, and about `pane.setPreferredSize` method, dont do anything until specifying the location and the size of the panel using `setBounds(x,y,width,height)`.

Answer (score 5):

If you see the **pack() function it is not in JFrame.java but Window.java**

```
public void pack() {
    Container parent = this.parent;
    if (parent != null && parent.getPeer() == null) {
        parent.addNotify();
    }
    if (peer == null) {
        addNotify();
    }
    Dimension newSize = getPreferredSize();
    if (peer != null) {
        setClientSize(newSize.width, newSize.height);
    }

    if(beforeFirstShow) {
        isPacked = true;
    }

    validateUnconditionally();
}
```

now if you see **getPreferredSize() function in Container.java**

```
@Deprecated
public Dimension preferredSize() {
    /* Avoid grabbing the lock if a reasonable cached size value
     * is available.
     */
    Dimension dim = prefSize;
    if (dim == null || !(isPreferredSizeSet() || isValid())) {
        synchronized (getTreeLock()) {
            prefSize = (layoutMgr != null) ?
                layoutMgr.preferredLayoutSize(this) :
                super.preferredSize();
            dim = prefSize;
        }
    }
    if (dim != null){
        return new Dimension(dim);
    }
    else{
        return dim;
    }
}
```

Everything boils down to `layoutMgr.preferredLayoutSize(this);`
Since you are not setting the layout(or null) you are getting that issue. Either remove that statement or use some layout.

Comment: I am just saying everything boils down to setting layout. Highlight is just for the info if OP want to browse the code. I don't see anything nonsense here.

Comment: Fair enough, I read too little of your answer, too quickly, and was mistakenly thinking you were suggesting that `pack()` was not a method that could be used for a frame.  My bad.  :P  ..and a belated +1 :)

Comment: Happens... No worries :)

Comment: And +1 from me too :)

Answer (score 2):

Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.

To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or combinations of them, along with layout padding & borders for white space.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17797593/418556) for tips on how to:

1. Combine layouts.
2. Provide white space using layout constructor arguments & borders.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue luckly, I solved with one line code. May this will also help you try to follow these steps:

1- Goto in your file code

2- In start of code find this line:

```
            initComponents();
```

3- Just add this new code after this line:

```
this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
```

The keyword "this" here representing your current top-level component, so new dimensions as (300, 300) is applied here. You may change this 300 values according to your required frame / component size.